# How to open programatically bootstrap mobile navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to discover the way to open the bootstrap mobile navbar when a button is clicked.

```
$("#myCustomBtn").click(function(){
   // Magic code goes here!
});
```

No matters is I need to use jQuery.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you haven't provided something that you have tried, so it's easier to see where are you stuck. Just saying "I need code for this" is not going to attract much people that want to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responsive navbar uses the [collapse plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse), you can use a link with the `href` attribute, or a button with the `data-target` attribute of the button in your navbar. [Here's an example](http://codepen.io/ocordova/pen/KrBJVK)

**EDIT:**

If you want to do it via jQuery you can call the [collapse methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods): `.collapse('toggle')`, `.collapse('show')` or `.collapse('hide')`

I updated the [example](http://codepen.io/ocordova/pen/KrBJVK).

Comment: Great! But I really need call the function that makes that effect, so when some event occurs I want to collapse the navbar. Do you know which is the command to do that? Thanks for answering.

Comment: I edited my answer with a jQuery example, I hope it helps (:

Comment: It helps! thanks, I can't upvote your answer, but I had marked as right answer.